# Fatal Error Message

Tags: php, sql

Content-type: text/html

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in **/home/content/18/8476518/html/training/emailOverdo.php** on line **88**

***what does this mean?!***

```
$courses[] = array('name' => $obj->name, 'length' => $obj->length);
} else {
    $query = "SELECT address FROM email LEFT JOIN managers ON (email.id=managers.person_id) WHERE branch_id='".$branch_id."' AND tier='1' AND email.category='2'";
    $managers = $db->query($query);
    while($manager = $managers->fetch_object())
    {
        notifyManager($manager->address, $courses, $first_name, $last_name, $day);
    }
```

Comment: **warning** your code might be vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: your query is not executed i think

Comment: more precisely that $managers is not what you think because you are trying to access fetch_object on it. so by that logic, backtrace it to $db. are you sure that's a valid connection and your query is not returning an error?

Comment: There is no line # 88 in your code

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using MySQLI or PDO?

Answer (score 2):

Your Query maybe returns something like `null` or `false` (depending on your Database Class)

Either your Query is wrong or you have no Data that could be selected.

You shuld check $managers for `null` or what ever you expected in error case:

```
if ($managers !== null) {
    //while()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**EXAMPLE.**
This is your dbc class

```
<?php

class dbc {

    public $dbserver = 'server';
    public $dbusername = 'user';
    public $dbpassword = 'pass';
    public $dbname = 'db';

    function openDb() {    
        try {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbserver . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';charset=utf8', '' . $this->dbusername . '', '' . $this->dbpassword . '');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("error, please try again");
        }        
        return $db;
    }

    function getAllData($qty) {
        //prepared query to prevent SQL injections
        $query = "select * from TABLE where qty = ?";
        $stmt = $this->openDb()->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $qty, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $rows;
    }    
?>
```

your PHP page:

```
<?php 
require "dbc.php";
$db = new dbc;

$getList = $db->getAllData(25);

foreach ($getList as $key=> $row) {
         echo $row['columnName'] .' key: '. $key;
    }
```

Comment: I'm...um, how does this answer the question?

Comment: somewhat. it addresses his issues with loops, addresses his issues with unprepared queries and uses PDO. I can't write his whole code for him ;)

Comment: your example never instantiates the class. $db = new dbc;

Comment: @ChrisForrence nice to see someone using my code! It is my standard response for quite some time!

Comment: @Andrew - I also noticed that while Googling "$getList = $db->getAllData(25);", that you've used this answer five times ;) But you're right; your first usage of it predates the pastebin code, so I did remove my earlier comment.